# Effect of Breadcrumbs in SEO and How to do it correctly?

Tags: seo, google, breadcrumbs

Is there any effect of breadcrumbs in SEO?

This is my blog posts structure

- example.com/blog/what-is-seo
- example.com/blog/seo-tips

This is my category structure

- example.com/category/seo

WordPress generate Breadcrumb as follows in my site (I have seen that other many sites are same)

- example.com->seo->what-is-seo

It is basically `example.com->category-name->post-name`

I feel like it should be `example.com->blog->post-name` according blog post structure. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, breadcrumbs affect SEO both directly and indirectly.

Directly: by adding correctly marked-up breadcrumbs (such as by using Schema.org), you are telling Google where on your site your content is found. So grouping articles by category is beneficial - you are reinforcing that you're not just writing a one-off piece, but you have a full category of related articles.

Indirectly: also by using correctly marked-up breadcrumbs, the way your site is listed in the SERPs will be a little different. Without breadcrumbs, your SERP contains the title linked to your page, followed by the URL of your page, followed by a description. With breadcrumbs, instead of showing the full long URL of your page (or Google truncating it with ...), Google will show your domain, followed by `>` and then each breadcrumb. So visitors will see that you have a full category, and not have to read through the full long URL, making it a little more likely that they will pick your listing and click on your link versus a competitor's.

Comment: *...grouping articles by category is beneficial - you are reinforcing...* I am pretty sure this level of analysis does not exist or is beneficial to search relevancy. Instead, the semantic values of the link url and text could be beneficial to search relevancy. In other words, it is just a link and adds nothing more than a link can add except that it is structured semantically from broad to specific in order. It is a set of clues just like any set of links except organized specifically for a purpose. Search engines do not cluster pages by topics outside of existing LSI methods. No need to.

Answer (score 0):

Breadcrumbs are very important in the SEO.

There are 3 types of Breadcrumbs in SEO-

1. Location-based Breadcrumbs -- Multiple Level Site Hierarchy
2. Attribute-based Breadcrumbs -- Based on Users Action History-based
3. Path-based Breadcrumbs -- Visitors path is followed

We are using the Path based Breadcrumbs here. So we can use example.com->category-name->post-name. But don't link the current page (post-name), still mention it in breadcrumbs trial.  There are many benefits of Breadcrumbs like -
1)They help the Search Engines to how pages are related.
2)Helps in Interlinking of Pages
3)Enhance User Experience

So always Breadcrumbs are good for User as well as Google robots to navigate through the website.